# How to assign a name to each element of a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Consider the following code which sorts a list based on other list contents. 

My question is related to sorted list i want to assign a name to each element and print the sorted names instead of elements any help

```
 Processes = input("   Enter the  processes times & arrival times separated by a comma: ")
 BurstTimes = Processes[::2]
 ArrivalTimes = Processes[1::2]
 print '   Burst Times:', BurstTimes, '\n', '   Arrival Times', ArrivalTimes,'\n',
 list1, list2 =  BurstTimes, ArrivalTimes
 indices1 = range(len(list1))
 indices1.sort(key=lambda x: list2[x])
 list1 = map(lambda i: list1[i], indices1)
 print 'The Processes executed in this order: ', list1
```

for example the input list contains elements 19 14 36 
how to assign a name to each element say A for 1st element, B for 2nd and C for 3rd
and the output is sorted list ( 14, 19, 36) but the printed list on console i want it to be (B, A,C)

Comment: @sshashank124 Question updated

Answer (score 4):

To assign a name to each element of a list, you should use a `dictionary` instead.

Here is an example:

```
a = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 4, 'watermelon': 5}
```

Dictionaries are in the form of `{key:value, key:value, key:value, ...}`

You can get a `value` in the dictionary that corresponds to its `key`. In the example above, you would do:

```
>>> print a['apple']
2
>>> a['banana']+a['watermelon']
5
```

You can access the `keys`, `values`, or both of a dictionary as follows:

```
>>> a.keys()
['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon']

>>> a.values()
[2,4,5]

>>> a.items()
[('apple', 2), ('banana', 4), ('watermelon', 5)]
```

However, you must note that dictionaries are not sorted and contain the data in whichever way is deemed more efficient. If you can about order of elements, use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

To create a dict out of two lists, you can do:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: Great but how can this applied on unknown sizi user input array can it be  a = {'apple': list[0], 'banana': list(1) and so on?

Comment: @user3547642, Please see my answer. Updated last line

Comment: great effort but seems that the answer is little far away from my question i want to assign a name to each element in the list before sort and print the sorted list in names not elements, note that size of list is unknown because it's user input

Comment: @user3547642, I don't understand. Can you please update your question with a sample of what the lists look like and what they would look like afterwards and the expected output.